# Can I connect a slimport to a DVI only screen using an HDMI to DVI adapter?

Tags: hdmi, slimport

I have a Nexus 4. I would like to connect it to my desktop screen but it only has DVI (currently I'm using HDMI to DVI adapter). Would slimport work anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works! However there is no guarantee that it will work with every DVI screen.